# Codeception How to test if a User has a Role

Tags: testing, laravel, relationships, codeception

I am trying to get into the habit of writing tests as I go.
I am using Laravel 4.2 to build an application that registers Users and assigns different roles to different user types.

I want to write a test that will check to see if a User has a Role. I am using Entrust to manage my Roles/Permissions and Laracasts/TestDummy to generate dummy objects. 
The Roles are stored in a pivot table, so I am essentially testing for the existance of a many to many relationship
The TestDummy documentation states that I need to define my objects and their relationships in a fixtures.yml file and gives an example

```
Post:
  title: Hello World $string
  body: $text
  published_at: $date
  author_id:
    type: Author

Author:
    name: John Doe $integer
```

The above layout defines a one to one relationship. A post has An Author. 
What I am trying to test for is A User has A Role, where many Users can have Many Roles

I want to know how to define this in my fixtures.yml file
in my mind

If I wanted to test a Many to Many Relationship (Many Users have Many Roles) could I reference it like this?

```
Excel\Users\User:
  username: $string$integer
  email: $string$integer@example.com
  password: $string
  created_at: $date
  updated_at: $date

\Role:
  name: $string
  created_at: $date
  updated_at: $date

Assigned_Role:
  user_id:
    type: Excel\Users\User
  role_id:
    type: \Role
```

The problem as I see it is that Assigned_Role does not have a model as it is just a pivot table

How could I test if a User has a specific Role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TestDummy only supports generating belongs to relations. You can try something like this, assuming you want to test a method on `User` like `hasRole($role)`.

```
$user = Factory::create('Excel\Users\User');
$role = Factory::create('Role');

$user->roles()->attach($role);
$this->assertTrue($user->hasRole($role));

$user->roles()->detach($role);
$this->assertFalse($user->hasRole($role));
```

Comment: Assigned_Role is the name of the pivot table and does not have a model attached. But this works perfectly when I do $role = Factory::create('\Role') . thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Whoops - fixed up the answer now!